# Windows Event Viewer Event Information

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, reboot, event-viewer

I am looking for information on a few specific Windows Event Viewer events that appear to occur on a system that I am using that has unexpected behavior.  I can look through the event viewer and save all of the logs without issue but as I am looking for a more detailed explanation of possible causes of a few events I am only finding old forum posts that generally contain the same Event ID.

Is there a single repository of information from Windows or elsewhere that would contain a more detailed explanation of various events?  The events in question that I am looking for are the following:

Critical Kernel-Power failure (Event ID 142)
[image]

I am mostly curious about what is either pinging (or more likely no longer pinging) the hardware watchdog; the HAL error underneath the Kernel-Power critical failure also mentions that the hardware watchdog was triggered.

This is all after a reboot from a shutdown event, the shutdown is somehow tripping the watchdog causing Windows to crash right before automatically rebooting and before I turn this feature off I would like to find a root cause.

Comment: http://www.eventid.net/ (currently down for me)

Comment: Since each application can write to the Windows Event Logs a self-defined message and ID, even an app you create, there cannot be a central repository for all events. Look up the application that wrote to the log.

Comment: I suppose that was a question I didn't know to ask @DrMoishePippik.  Because this is a rather custom built computer similar to a National Instruments PXIe chassis, is there any way for me to determine the source of the failures I'm seeing from the available information in the event viewer?  I am not particularly experienced with parsing through these types of things and am not entirely sure what information given in the more detailed sections of the event viewer would lead me to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try Nirsoft's free [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html) for an easier-to-follow display of Windows Events. This may help to trace the sequence of events leading to the shutdown by the system watchdog.

[image: Nirsoft's Full Event Log Viewer]

The Windows *Event Viewer* keeps an immense amount of data, but makes it less easy to search because you'd need to create a custom view to see all relevant logs together. Nirsoft's tool lets you search (filter) by date/time, by severity, Event ID, etc. It also puts information in a more readable form in the bottom pane. Use this to search backwards to find the last few events *before* the abrupt shutdown ([abend](https://www.definitions.net/definition/Abend), abnormal ending in geek). Try to find the *first* process that broke, causing the chain that led to termination. From that, find the application *running* that process.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a "official" repository.  This is where I start when looking for event ids:

http://www.chicagotech.net/wineventid.htm